# Docker failed to start service utility VM (createreadwrite): mysql

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, windows-server-2019

I have a a clean Windows Server 2019 VM. I installed docker on it. Then I'm trying to install mysql. I run `docker pull mysql` it is successfully pulled. When I try to run docker `run --name=MySqlServer -d mysql`

I receive the following error:

```
docker : docker: Error response from daemon: failed to start service utility VM (createreadwrite): kernel 'C:\Program Files\Linux Containers\kernel' not found.
```

I am new to containers and I don't know how to troubleshoot this issue. I have already set experimental:true to daemon.json